# SubNavigation within Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, ngroute

I am trying to create an application that has 2 (potentially 3) levels of navigation.  I am using @RouterConfig to create this navigation.

When I created the first level of navigation the application worked fine, so I went through the same process to create level 2 of the navigation.

The navigation format I want to create is as follows

```
mainApplication (sidebar navigation)

---select (tabs)
   ---by Collection
   ---by Category
   ---by Range

---Inspect (tabs)
   ---forecast
   ---inventory
   ---purchase

---Other
   ---sublevel
   ---sublevel
   ---sublevel
---Other
   ---sublevel
   ---sublevel
---Other
```

I am receiving the following error which I don't understand...

Child routes are not allowed for "/inspect". Use "..." on the parent's route path.

In this example I am focusing on the sub-Navigation within the Inspec component. Below is the code...

app.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit}  from 'angular2/core';
import { Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ,ROUTE_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';


//ROUTER PAGES
import {ProjectSelect}          from 'app/project.select'
import {ProjectInspect}         from 'app/project.inspect'


@Component({
    selector        :  'my-app',
    templateUrl :  'app/app.component.html',
    styleUrls   : ['app/app.component.css']
    directives  : [
                                        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
                                        ProjectSelect,
                                        ProjectInspect
        ]
})

@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/select',   name:'Select',  component: ProjectSelect, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/inspect',  name:'Inspect', component: ProjectInspect},
])


export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    applicationTitle:String = "Slim 4 Angular"

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['Select']);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer">
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">{{applicationTitle}}</span>
        <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" [routerLink]="['Select']">Select</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" [routerLink]="['Inspect']">Inspect</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link">Order</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link">Intelligence</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link">Demand</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link">Introduce</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link">Update</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link">Promote</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
        <div class="page-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </main>
</div>
```

project.inspect.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit}  from 'angular2/core';
import { Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ,ROUTE_PROVIDERS,RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';


//ROUTER PAGES
import {WorkbenchForecast}      from 'app/workbench.forecast'
import {WorkbenchInventory}     from 'app/workbench.inventory'
import {WorkbenchPurchase}      from 'app/workbench.purchase'



@Component({
    selector        :  'project-inspect',
    templateUrl     :  'app/project.inspect.html',
    styleUrls   : ['app/app.component.css']
    directives  : [
                                        ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,
                                        WorkbenchForecast,
                                        WorkbenchInventory,
                                        WorkbenchPurchase
        ]
})


@RouteConfig([
    {path: './forecast',    name:'Forecast',    component: WorkbenchForecast, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: './inventory', name:'Inventory', component: WorkbenchInventory},
    {path: './purchase',    name:'Purchase',    component: WorkbenchPurchase},
])


export class ProjectInspect implements OnInit {

    projectTitle:String = "Inspect"

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['Forecast']);
  }
}
```

project.inspect.html

```
<div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
  <div class="mdl-tabs__tab-bar">
      <a href="inspect/#workbenck1" class="mdl-tabs__tab" [routerLink]="['Forecast']">Forecast</a>
      <a href="inspect/#workbench2" class="mdl-tabs__tab" [routerLink]="['Inventory']">Inventory</a>
      <a href="inspect/#workbench3" class="mdl-tabs__tab" [routerLink]="['Purchase']">Purchase</a>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if two levels of navigation can be achieved in Angular2 but I hope it can.  If anyone can help me with the correct implementation I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

In `app.component.ts` make the following change:

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/select/...',   name:'Select',  component: ProjectSelect, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/inspect/...',  name:'Inspect', component: ProjectInspect},
])
```

Comment: I have tried that and am now receiving a new error:

EXCEPTION: Link "["Select"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction. in [null]

Comment: Try adding `useAsDefault: true` to one of your child routes

Comment: I have tried this but the error still remains  the same

Comment: Just noticed in your `RouteConfig` for `project.inspect.ts` that you've prepended the path with a `.` which is not correct. If that is also the case in your select component, remove that and try again.

Comment: Well spotted doovers!  I have removed the offending dots, but i still have the same error: 

EXCEPTION: Link "["Select"]" does not resolve to a terminal instruction. in [null]

If I could give you kudos for time-spent I would!

Comment: Hmmm... have a read of this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34324194/2570590) and see does it help?